# Hide and show div in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I want to  show a div that is hidden when I click on a Button. I am working with Angular7 I tried some methods but they didn't work. Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can use *ngIf

**Template:**

```
<div *ngIf="display">Test Data</div>
<input type="button" value="click" (click)="update"/>
```

**Component:**

```
display = true;
update(){
   this.display = !this.display;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can link an *ngIf directive to your component with a variable set to True,
then on the button click modify the variable to false.

Template:

```
<div *ngIf='variable'></div>
<button (click)='showContent()'></button>
```

Component:

```
  variable = true;
  showContent() {
  this.variable = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change display or visibility depending on what you need.

use ngStyle or ngClass to set it based on a condition